# Secure internet browsing

Tags: web-browser, security

I took a job that requires me to browse various websites without an adblocker and also have to visit potentially dangerous websites.
Since these tasks are performed on my mainrig I want to be sure I'm on the safe side. What software could you recommend?

So far I thought about

- running Ubuntu in a VM, which is too slow for my taste
- getting a tool like Sandboxie and set up my browser, Flash player etc. to run in said box
- setting up a dual boot with my current Windows 8.1
- using a second account without administrator, but I’m not sure if this is secure enough

Comment: You should definitely use a VM in addition to other measures. The amount of isolation provided by a VM is much greater than things like SandBoxie or Internet Security apps can offer. And as you said, using a different OS in the VM, especially one with relatively little exploits like Ubuntu, is also very good protection. Get a faster computer.

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks for your input, maybe I have to tweak some settings however I would not consider my PC for an update yet. It's a 2500K @ 4Ghz, 8GB RAM, GTX 580, ...

Comment: @JanDoggen When running oracle VM my hosts CPU load barely exceeds 30%, and that's just the spikes. I'm stuck with 10% in the meantime. No question it runs slow... Any input?

Comment: [You're not the only one](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+VM+ubuntu+slow)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why no ad blocker?

Comment: @KnightOfNi Because I have to be able to see website as its meant. If pop ups are present and decrease the user experience I have to see that e.g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Comodo Internet Security](https://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php). It has a built-in sandbox which allows you to safely run applications or browse the internet. It also has shortcuts to sandboxed browsers in a Windows widget:

[image]

You can also run a virtualization mode which is basically similar to a virtual machine but without having to install another operating system.

A faster way is to download [Comodo Dragon](https://www.comodo.com/home/browsers-toolbars/browser.php) which has a `switch to virtual mode` option in the application menu:

[image]

This mode automatically relaunches the application in the sandbox

Comment: @idkfa No problem. If the answer helped, then you can accept it using tihe green checkmark on the left

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to mark the answer. I would have marked it instantly but I think there was something about a waiting period before being able to do that. Didn't test to mark it though.